# How to compare 2 lists of dictionnaries?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to compare 2 lists of dictionaries.

Please find an example below.

```
list1 = [
         {'code': '1111', 'description': 'Test'},
         {'code': '2222', 'description': 'Hello World'},
         {'code': '3333', 'description': 'Stack'},
         {'code': '4444', 'description': 'Gozilla'},
        ]

list2 = [
         {'code': '3333', 'description': 'Stack'},
         {'code': '4444', 'description': 'Megatron'},
         {'code': '5555', 'description': 'Winnie the Pooh'}
        ]
```

I am trying to :

1. If ['code'] from list2 exist in list1, and if ['description'] is different, place it in a new list "updates".
2. If ['code'] from list2 does not exist in list1, place it in a new list "new".

At the end the 2 new lists from my example should look like that :

```
updates = [
           {'code': '4444', 'description': 'Megatron'}
          ]

new =     [
           {'code': '5555', 'description': 'Winnie the Pooh'}
          ]
```

Any ideas how I could achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `list1` to dict to make comparing codes easier:

```
list1 = [
         {'code': '1111', 'description': 'Test'},
         {'code': '2222', 'description': 'Hello World'},
         {'code': '3333', 'description': 'Stack'},
         {'code': '4444', 'description': 'Gozilla'},
        ]

list2 = [
         {'code': '3333', 'description': 'Stack'},
         {'code': '4444', 'description': 'Megatron'},
         {'code': '5555', 'description': 'Winnie the Pooh'}
        ]

updates = []
new = []

tmp = {d['code']: d['description'] for d in list1}
for d in list2:
    if d['code'] in tmp and d['description'] != tmp[d['code']]:
        updates.append(d)
    elif not d['code'] in tmp:
        new.append(d)

print(updates)
print(new)
```

Prints:

```
[{'code': '4444', 'description': 'Megatron'}]
[{'code': '5555', 'description': 'Winnie the Pooh'}]
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you Andrej :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Otherwise,for example  4444 in between of list1 and list2

new_list = []
if list1[3].get('code')==list2[1].get('code'):
   new_list.append(list2[1])

print(new_list)
```